# Каким образом авторизоваться на Facebook-e?

Tags: jquery, авторизация, facebook, php

Привет ребята, такое задание: у меня есть форма авторизации для facebook. `form-action, method, email-input, pass-input`, то есть имена полей и формы сходны с файс-кими формами. Но при отправлении запроса facebook выводит ощибку.

> Security Notice For your security,
> never enter your Facebook password on
> sites not located on Facebook.com

Пожалуйста, помогите, если кто знает.

Comment: Все Решил вместо localhost написал 127.0.0.1 спасибо свем кто помог...;)

Answer (score 1):

так не получится, нужно создавать аппликацию на фейсбуке и авторизовать через неё по OAUTH.
рекомендую к прочтению https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

вот пример работающего кода скрипта-коннектора connector.php для авторизации (подставьте только сюда параметры своей аппликации), работает в отдельном окне. думаю разберетесь

```
<?php
session_start();

define('FB_APP_ID', 'application id');
define('FB_APP_SECRET', 'application secret');

if (!isset($_SESSION["UserFacebookID"])) {
    $my_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/connector.php";
    $code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : '';
    if (empty($code)) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
        $dialog_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='
    . FB_APP_ID                 .'&scope=email,user_birthday,user_location&display=popup&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) . '&state='
    . $_SESSION['state'];
    header('Location: ' . $dialog_url); exit;
} else {
    if ($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
        $token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
        . 'client_id=' . FB_APP_ID . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url)
        . '&client_secret=' . FB_APP_SECRET . '&code=' . $code;
        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);
        $graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' . $params['access_token'];
        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
        if ($user->id){
            // OK
            var_dump($user);
        } else {
            echo '<script>window.close()</script>';
        }
    } else {
        exit('The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.');
    }
    }
} else {
    echo '<script>window.close()</script>';
}
```